# skipping shippingmethod step in magento onepage checkout

Tags: templates, magento, customization, checkout

Busy on a project and I need to skip the shipping method step. Shop contains simple and grouped products. There is no need for shipping so I tried:
- disabling the shipping methods results in not able to checkout
- only turning on the free shipping results in the step still visible

- changing template code and deleting the shipping_methods section from progress.phtml or setting is_show to false results in no able to checkout
- changing the template as above and and the opcheckout.js so it skips the shipping_methods step and goes to payment results in shipping_address not pointing to payment (skipping shipping_methods).

What am I missing? Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use virtual products instead of simple.
Or you can make some code changes like in [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20100302075827/http://www.igorkrasnykh.com/2009/02/24/removing-shipping-and-payment-steps).

Comment: Hi Joseph, Your link pointed me in the right direction. I only needed to bypass the shipping_method selection and it worked with minor rewrites of the code as suggested in the the article!

Comment: The link is dead :-(.

Comment: Yes the link is dead; actually it redirects to a page which kind of promotes the writer; I don't see that very often.

Comment: You can see the actual page using archive.org cache, I updated the link. Here it is: http://web.archive.org/web/20100302075827/http://www.igorkrasnykh.com/2009/02/24/removing-shipping-and-payment-steps